# React-native введение

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Вот никак не могу понять как работает React-Native.Зачем нужен Python,npm?И как так получается один код работает под ios и android?При команде "react-native init apppp" на cmd как создаются папки ios,android,node_modules...

Answer (score 0):

Нативный потому, что не использует WebView - используются обернутые нативные компоненты. За счет обертки работает и под ios и под android. Использует движок JavaScriptCore, которые можно и под ios и под android скомпилировать, как и большинство современных движков.

Comment: Спасибо...а можно подробнее?Что за движок?Я гуглю но как то слишком запутанно.."The JavaScriptCore Framework provides the ability to evaluate JavaScript programs from within Swift, Objective-C, and C-based apps. You can use also use JavaScriptCore to insert custom objects to the JavaScript environment" Для Androida разве не Java нужен?

Comment: @Sura это javascript движок. Как v8 для google chrome. Компилирует и исполняет js код. 
Почитать немного подробнее можно здесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA_JavaScript